# Dim a ListRow only if it is in focus

Tags: android, android-tv, leanback

I currently encounter a problem with implementing a custom focus dimmer on a ListRow in an Android TV App.

Expected behaviour: 
Each item in a ListRow has a transparent grey overlay. This overlay is invisible whenever the item has focus and visible when an item is not in focus. Now the tricky part: this behaviour is only expected if the ListRow itself is in focus. This means: whenever I focus another ListRow, the navigation or any other view the grey overlays of all items are supposed to be invisible (as if all items were in focus).

Leanback's ListRowPresenter provides both a useFocusDimmer Boolean and a selectEffectEnabled Boolean that are supposed to provide said behaviour. However when I set selectEffectEnabled = true only the previously selected items are dimmed, not (as expected) all unfocused items.

What I did instead: each item view now has a OnFocusChangeListener like this:

```
setOnFocusChangeListener { _, hasFocus ->
     transparent_overlay.visibility = if (hasFocus) View.GONE else View.VISIBLE
}
```

Is it possible to also check if the item view's parent view has focus so that the overlay is also gone if the parent has lost focused? If not: is there any other way to implement the described behaviour?

Thank you in advance!